# TextboxFor in MVC is not binding to Model inside a for loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My Viewmodel (contains a number of submodels) is:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<tblQuestion> DemoQuestions { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<tblQuestion> TechQuestions { get; set; }

    public List<tblAnswer> DemoQ1Answers { get; set; }
    public List<tblAnswer> DemoQ2Answers { get; set; }
    public List<tblAnswer> TechAnswers { get; set; }

    public string selectedAnswerIDforQ1 { get; set; }
    public string selectedAnswerIDforQ2 { get; set; }
}
```

My tblAnswer model is like below:

```
public partial class tblAnswer
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string AnswerDescription { get; set; }
    public string Q1Other { get; set; }
}
```

This is my view code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Display", "Questionnaire", FormMethod.Post))
{
    foreach (tblQuestion question in Model.DemoQuestions)
    {
        <p>@question.QuestionDescription</p>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.DemoQ1Answers.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (question.QuestionID == 1)
            {
                <div class="col-md-4">
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.selectedAnswerIDforQ1, Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID)
                @Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerDescription
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID)
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerDescription)
                @if (Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID == 4)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].Q1Other)     
                }
            </div>
            }  
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

When I press submit, my textbox value in the model is null. Means, `mymodel.DemoQ1Answers[3].Q1Other` is null. All other model values are bound with model values in the view except this one.

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Display(ViewModel mymodel)
{ 
    foreach (var demoqstns in mymodel.DemoQuestions)
    {
        int AnswerSelected = 0;
        string otherText = null;
        if (qstnID == 1)
        {
            AnswerSelected = Convert.ToInt32(mymodel.selectedAnswerIDforQ1);
            if (AnswerSelected == 4)
            {
                otherText = mymodel.DemoQ1Answers[3].Q1Other;
            }
        }
        else if (qstnID == 2)
        {
            AnswerSelected = Convert.ToInt32(mymodel.selectedAnswerIDforQ2);
        }
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Textbox for `Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].Q1Other` is only rendered `if (Model.DemoQ1Answers[i].AnswerID == 4)`. Is this the case for your test data? Maybe you want to post this value back as hidden field in the `else` path?

Answer (score -2):

you have to use for loop instated of foreach
 for (var i = 0; i < Model.Orders.Count(); i++)
     @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.Orders[i].CustomerID)

the index value i appears in the lambda expression for each form element being generated by the loop, The TextBoxFor HtmlHelper is used, rather than the more general (and automagic) DisplayFor and EditorFor.

Comment: if you read the posted code, you would see that `for` is being used